# How can I add text in Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: final-cut-pro

One thing I really hate about Final Cut Pro X is the inability to add basic text, like you could on all previous versions of Final Cut Pro.  It seems all text has to be entered as "titles" - and although you can edit these titles to look like basic text, it really isn't the same thing.

Is there any way to get basic text in Final Cut Pro X?

Comment: Define "basic text." You can add a simple, stationary title, change the font and location, and configure in and out points for it. So I'm not really sure what you mean by "basic text."

Answer (score 2):

You could doit with `Control-T` to add the basic text title.